# XeLaTeX: xtabular package fails to work

Tags: tables, xetex, xtab

I am trying to make my resume neat and tidy. So, going for `LaTeX/XeLaTex`. Resume [Here](http://crocodoc.com/2oUN8hc)

The problem is, even though I use the `xtab` package to put my long tables across multiple pages, for some reason, the tables get broken even before reaching the bottom margin!

I also tried to decrease the bottom margin by using the `anysize` package and `\margin{1cm}{1cm}{0cm}{-10cm}`. But no use.

Any way out of this problem?

Comment: Without more information, I don't think anyone will be able to even guess at the source of your problem. Could you provide a complete working example?

Comment: If @AlanMunn's answer does not solve your problem, I would suggest that you compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xtab` package tries to eliminate bad page breaks as much as possible, but if you encounter them it has two parameters that can be modified to affect the breaks:

From the documentation p. 6:

> The command `\shrinkheight{⟨length⟩}` may be used after the first `\\`
>   in the table to modify the allowed height of the table on that page. A
>   positive `⟨length⟩` decreases the allowed space on the page and a
>   negative `⟨length⟩` increases the allowed space. For example:
>   `\shrinkheight{2\baselineskip}` decreases the space per page by two
>   lines. `\shrinkheight{-\baselineskip}` increases the space per page by
>   one line. Note that I have never tried using this command so I cannot
>   comment on its efficacy. Instead, I use the `\xentrystretch` command
>   when necessary.
>
> The command `\xentrystretch{⟨decimal-fraction⟩}` can be used before a
>   table to modify the amount of vertical space apparently consumed by
>   each entry in the subsequent table(s). The default is
>   `\xentrystretch{0.1}` which specifies a 10% overestimate in the
>   vertical space. Similarly, `\xentrystretch{0.25}` will overestimate
>   the space by 25%.

Comment: Yeah!! Thats right.. `\shrinkheight{-7\normalbaselineskip}` solved all the pre break-up issues.